# ASP.NET current Session object - inject log logic

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

In the app I am working on we are using an InProc ASP.NET SessionState object.

I'd like to find a way to log a message whenever some code reads or writes into the Session object.

I am aware of the Item[] index, and I suppose I should inject the code somehow.. or maybe inherit the HttpSessionState class?

Options, ideas, experience...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom SessionStateProvider, and from within that provider you can instantiate an instance of the InProcSessionStateStore and use that to do all of the work related to session store handling.

And from within this custom SessionStateProvider you can perform all of the logging you.

So here's what you'd have to do:

1. Create a new class that inherits the SessionStateStoreProviderBase class, assume it is named "MySessionStateProvider"
2. Implement all of the abstract class methods.
3. From within the constructor of your class, use Reflection to create an instance of the InProcSessionStateStore class (this is used by ASP.NET to store Session State when configured for InProc - your case)
   Store this instance in a variable
4. Use the above instance of InProc class in all overridden methods to perform the necessary actions.
5. Configure this new provider in the Web.Config
6. Last but not least, implement your logging

Here's the sample code (and a link to how someone else has created a custom provider, should you need a working example with further information).
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatestoreproviderbase(v=vs.110).aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/102000/ASP-NET-Custom-Session-Store-Provider-compatible-w

Web.Config

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="custom_provider" ... >
      <providers>
        <add name="custom_provider" type="Xxxx.xxx.MySessionStateProvider"/>
      </providers>
</sessionState>
```

MySessionStateProvider class code:

```
public class MySessionStateProvider : System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateStoreProviderBase {
    private readonly SessionStateStoreProviderBase InProcSessionStore;
    public MySessionStateProvider() {
        var inProcSessionStoreType = typeof(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateStoreProviderBase).Assembly.GetType("System.Web.SessionState.InProcSessionStateStore");
        InProcSessionStore = (System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateStoreProviderBase)Activator.CreateInstance(inProcSessionStoreType);
        InProcSessionStore.Initialize(null, null);
    }
    public override SessionStateStoreData CreateNewStoreData(HttpContext context, int timeout) {
        return InProcSessionStore.CreateNewStoreData(context, timeout);
    }

    public override void CreateUninitializedItem(HttpContext context, string id, int timeout) {
        InProcSessionStore.CreateUninitializedItem(context, id, timeout);
    }

    public override void Dispose() {
        InProcSessionStore.Dispose();
    }

    //... Implement the rest of the method in the same manner.        

    public override bool SetItemExpireCallback(SessionStateItemExpireCallback expireCallback) {
        return InProcSessionStore.SetItemExpireCallback(expireCallback);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just an addition.

(Edit: I made it a little more generic)

first, an interface to abstract the wrap

```
interface ISessionStateItemCollectionWrapper : ISessionStateItemCollection
{
    ISessionStateItemCollection WrappedCollection { get; set; }
}
```

Since I want to log when a session item is read or written I added a wrapper for the ISessionStateItemCollection

```
public class SessionStateItemCollectionWithInstrumentation : ISessionStateItemCollectionWrapper
{
    public ISessionStateItemCollection WrappedCollection { get; set; }

        //...
        //...
        //...

        public object this[string name]
        {
            get
            {
                LogRead();
                return _wrappedCollection[name];
            }
            set
            {
                LogWrite();
                _wrappedCollection[name] = value;
            }
        }

        //...
        //More log on some methods
        //...
    }
```

Then, to inject it, I inherited SessionStateStoreData

```
class SessionStoreDataItemsInjector<T> : SessionStateStoreData where T:ISessionStateItemCollectionWrapper, new()
{
    public SessionStoreDataItemsInjector(SessionStateStoreData wrappedData)
        : base(new T()
        {
            WrappedCollection = wrappedData.Items
        }, wrappedData.StaticObjects, wrappedData.Timeout)
    {
    }
}
```

and then I wired it to the class that Don provided

```
abstract class InProcSessionStateInjected<T> : SessionStateStoreProviderBase where T : ISessionStateItemCollectionWrapper, new()
{
    private SessionStateStoreProviderBase inProcSessionStore;

    public override void Initialize(string name, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection config)
    {
        var inProcSessionStoreType = typeof(SessionStateStoreProviderBase).Assembly.GetType("System.Web.SessionState.InProcSessionStateStore");
        inProcSessionStore = (SessionStateStoreProviderBase)Activator.CreateInstance(inProcSessionStoreType);

        inProcSessionStore.Initialize(name, config);
    }

    public override SessionStateStoreData CreateNewStoreData(HttpContext context, int timeout)
    {
        var sessionStateStoreData = inProcSessionStore.CreateNewStoreData(context, timeout);
        return sessionStateStoreData.Items.GetType() != typeof(T) ? new SessionStoreDataItemsInjector<T>(sessionStateStoreData) : sessionStateStoreData;
    }

    public override SessionStateStoreData GetItem(HttpContext context, string id, out bool locked, out TimeSpan lockAge, out object lockId, out SessionStateActions actions)
    {
        var sessionStateStoreData = inProcSessionStore.GetItem(context, id, out locked, out lockAge, out lockId, out actions);
        if (sessionStateStoreData != null && sessionStateStoreData.Items.GetType() != typeof(T))
        {
            return new SessionStoreDataItemsInjector<T>(sessionStateStoreData);
        }
        return sessionStateStoreData;
    }

    public override SessionStateStoreData GetItemExclusive(HttpContext context, string id, out bool locked, out TimeSpan lockAge, out object lockId, out SessionStateActions actions)
    {
        var sessionStateStoreData = inProcSessionStore.GetItemExclusive(context, id, out locked, out lockAge, out lockId, out actions);
        if (sessionStateStoreData != null && sessionStateStoreData.Items.GetType() != typeof(T))
        {
            return new SessionStoreDataItemsInjector<T>(sessionStateStoreData);
        }
        return sessionStateStoreData;
    }
```